# Get time from Instant and save in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I have "eventTime" field in Cassandra table with data type "time". I am trying to save current UTC time but could not. I declared field in Java as -

```
private Long eventTime;
```

Tried several ways to get time from Instant but incorrect data is getting saved.

> 1. Instant.now(clock).getLong(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND)

Saved "00:00:00.093563694" in Cassandra

> 2. LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(clock), ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour()

Saved "00:00:00.000000001" in Cassandra

If I directly run insert query in CQL with string value as '16:15:09.049909' then it worked.

Shall I change data type to "text" and save time as String.

Answer (score 1):

You can map `Instant` into Cassandra's `timestamp` if you use optional codecs from Java driver as described in documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#jdk-8

Add to pom.xml following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>  
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId> 
  <version>3.6.0</version> 
 </dependency>
```

And register codec when creating `Cluster` object:

```
import com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.jdk8.InstantCodec; 
import java.time.Instant; 
...
cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry()
     .register(InstantCodec.instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to save the current time to Cassandra?

`LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();`

You are extracting some information above in your code as `ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND` or `.getHour()`. Just use the local time entirely.

Comment: I changed the data type to LocalTime. In java object the time is showing 'eventTime=16:56:49.071111590' which is correct UTC time. But after save in Cassandra is showing '00:25:45.353809071'. Not sure how conversion is happening.